# Powershell: How to find an item in an array thats not an exact match?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array of items like so:

```
$arr = "server1", "server2", server3"
```

I have a search value:

```
$ser = "server3-test"
```

I want to find similar values in the array without doing modifications to the actual value I'm searching for itself (aka string splits etc).

So something like:

```
if($arr -contains (similar $ser)) {do stuff}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by filtering:

```
if (($arr | Where-Object { $_ -like 'server3*' })) {
    # do stuff
}

if ($arr.Where( { $_ -like 'server3*' } )) {
    # do stuff
}
```

You can also take advantage of the fact that `-like` and `-match` operators can operate on collections, and return a collection that satisfies the condition, and then further on the fact that an empty collection will evaluate `$false`:

```
if ($arr -like 'server3*') {
    # do stuff
}
```

After re-reading your question, I see that this is not quite what you are looking for.

In your example, the value in `$arr` is a subset of `$ser`, so you could do this:

```
if ($arr.Where( { $ser -match $_ } )) { }
```

But it's not clear if that will always be the case.

Perhaps something more safe, but also more verbose would be to check both against each other:

```
if (
    $arr | Where-Object {
        $_ -like "*$ser*" -or
        $ser -like "*$_*"
    } ) {
    # do stuff
}
```

To know what was actually matched, I'd suggest a slightly different approach:

```
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -like $ser) {
        # do stuff
        # $_ will refer to the array member that was matched
    }
}
```

The caveat here is that `# do stuff` will be executed once *for every match*, instead of once *if any match* was found.

Another possibility:

```
$itemsMatched = $arr -like $ser
if ($itemsMatched) {
    # do stuff (executed once)
}
```

In this case `$itemsMatched` will contain the array members that matched (it may be more than one).

Comment: This seems to work:

if($arr | Where-Object { $_ -like $ser) {do stuff}

Followup question if I may?
For logging purposes how would I see what it matched on?

Comment: This works:

    $arr = "server1", "server2", server3"
    $ser = "server3-test"
    if ($arr.Where( { $ser -match $_ } )) {
        "found"
     }
This does not

    $arr = "server1", "server2", server3"
    $ser = "server3-test"
    $arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -like $ser) {
        "found"
       }
     }

Ideally I'd like to use the second one because it would hopefully get me all matches and I could use it to "do stuff" once as well.

Comment: I guess doing in the match in reverse technically works since the original names are always going to be shorter than the search values. This works:

$arr = "server1", "server2", "server3"
$ser = "server3-test"
$matches = @()

$arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($ser -match $_) {
        "found"
    }
}

$matches